# Using grep and ls -a commands

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep, ls

Using an `ls –a` and `grep`, how would you list the name of all of the files in /usr starting with the letter p or the letter r or the letter s using a single grep command?

would this be right?

```
ls –a | grep [prs] /usr
```

Comment: Directly under `/usr` or at any level under `/usr`?

Comment: just directly under /usr

Comment: `echo /usr/[prs]*`...

Answer (score 21):

```
 ls -a /usr | grep '^[prs]'
```

Would select from the output of `ls -a /usr` (which is the list of files in `/usr` delimited by newline characters) the lines that start by either of the `p`, `r` or `s` characters.

That's probably what your teacher is expecting but it's wrong or at least not reliable.

File names can be made of many lines since the newline character is as valid a character as any in a file name on Linux or any unix. So that command doesn't return the files whose name starts with `p`, `q` or `s`, but the lines of the filenames that start with `p`, `q` or `s`. Generally, you can't post-process the output of `ls` reliably.

`-a` is to include hidden files, that is files whose name starts with `.`. Since you only want those that start with `p`, `q` or `s`, that's redundant.

Note that:

```
ls /usr | grep ^[pqs]
```

would be even more wrong. First `^` is a special character in a few shells like the Bourne shell, `rc`, `es` or `zsh -o extendedglob` (though OK in `bash` or other POSIX shells).

Then, in most shells (`fish` being a notable exception), `[pqs]` is a globbing operator. That means that `^[qps]` is meant to be expanded by the shell to the list of files that match that pattern (relative to the current directory).

So in those shells like `bash` that don't treat `^` specially, if there is a file called `^p` in the current directory, that will become

```
ls /usr | grep ^p
```

If there's no matching file, in `csh`, `tcsh`, `zsh` or `bash -O failglob`, you'll get an error message and the command will be cancelled. In `zsh -o extendedglob` where `^` is a globbing operator, `^[pqs]` would mean any file but `p`, `q` or `s`.

Answer (score 15):

If you're trying to find files, don't use `ls`.  Use the `find` command.

```
find /usr -name '[prs]*'
```

If you don't want to search the entire tree under /usr, do this:

```
find /usr -maxdepth 1 -name '[prs]*'
```

Answer (score 4):

The comment of @twalberg is perfect for the options you asked.
The echo ignores hidden files, but those will be filtered when you only want files starting with [prs].
When you want hidden files for other filters, a similar solution would be `ls -ad /usr/[prs]*`, where the -d option suppresses the listing of subdirs.
That solution will also show the full path, this can be suppressed when you go to the dir first. When you want to stay in your current directory, use a subshell for it.  I use && for skipping the ls when the /usr dir doesn't exist.

```
(cd /usr && ls -ad [prs]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd `ls` the directory and only then apply the `grep`. Also, you're missing the `^` character to filter out only the files that **start** with those letters:

```
$ ls -a /usr | grep ^[prs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
 find /usr -type f -name '[prs]*'
```

Comment: Because that would traverse everything under `/usr` and not just `/usr` itself.

Comment: That's easy fixed with a `-maxdepth` argument.  It's certainly much safer than parsing `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

I used for my csv, I hope it should help you too.

```
$ bash
bash-4.4$ ls *.csv | grep '^[Kk][Ss]*'
output: list of files
Let's say, you want the count also of files and not just list them
bash-4.4$ ls *.csv | grep '^[Kk][Ss]*'|wc -l
output: 42
Let's say you want size of files
bash-4.4$ ls -ls
```